# Multiplication doesn't return the exact result

Tags: vb.net

I'm working with two loops each serving for the distribution of data within a table.
except in the variable "mol" a value that I got from the split of an array, therefore I multiply it by the value contained in a NumericUpDown.
The multiplication is successful but when starting a new cycle, the value is obviously replaced. How can I do to keep in memory the value until now calculated and multiply it by the following values?

```
    Dim giocata = NumericUpDown1.Value

    For Each key In combinations
        For Each combination In key
            Dim valore = combination.Split(",")
            quota = Convert.ToDouble(valore(3), New CultureInfo("en-US")) 'utile per il punto
            MessageBox.Show(quota)
                mol = quota * giocata
                MessageBox.Show(mol)
                dt.Rows(contatore).Item(valore(4)) = valore(1) & "-" & valore(2)
        Next
        dt.Rows(contatore).Item(moltiplicatore(k)) = mol
        mol = 0
        contatore = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(contatore)
    Next
```

Problem example:

mol = 3.60 * 2 = 7.20

new loop

mol = 1.90 * 2 = 3.80

But should be:
mol = 3.60 * 2 = 7.20
new loop
mol = 1.90 * 2 * 7.20 =  27.36

Comment: you need a form/class level variable to store the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the inner loop you always recalculate the value of `mol` using the current values.
So, when you exit that loop the value of `mol` is always the last one calculated.

To fix your problem, according to your example data, you should multiply the current value of `mol` to the values of `(quota * giocata)` and set `mol` to the result of this multiplication

It is just (in VB.NET)

```
mol = mol * (quota * giocata)
```

But in the first loop you need to initialize the value `mol` otherwise the `0 * ...` produce zero as result. So you need to add an if to check if the variable `mol` is still to be set for the current loop on the `key` collection.

```
mol = 0
For Each combination In key
    Dim valore = combination.Split(",")
    quota = Convert.ToDouble(valore(3), New CultureInfo("en-US")) 'utile per il punto
    Dim temp = quota * giocata
    if mol = 0 Then
         mol = temp
    else
         mol = mol * temp
    End if
    dt.Rows(contatore).Item(valore(4)) = valore(1) & "-" & valore(2)
Next
```

Note also the need to move the setting to zero of mol at the beginning of the inner loop and not at the end of it if you need to have that value outside the loop

Comment: I had already tried so, this always returns 0 ...
if mol has not yet been calculated, then I will have 0

Comment: @JessePinkman you are right, this need to be addressed inside the loop with an if check on the value of mol